# What is the recommended directory to store website content (data) in FreeBSD?

Tags: apache-http-server, path, freebsd, default-settings

Assuming the server uses Apache, where it is the most adequate folder to place uploaded files, contents and data in FreeBSD? This question is the extension to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/635289/what-is-the-recommended-directory-to-store-website-content) but specific for FreeBSD.

The [Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-apache.html) only determines where the *code* files must be placed. For security reasons, *data* is kept separate from the DocumentRoot.

Looking at the [HIER section](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&sektion=7&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) it seems that I need to create a new folder under `/usr/local` perhaps `/usr/local/srv`  ?

It seems odd to me as it says such `/usr/local` should contain

> 'local executables, libraries, etc.'

but says nothing about data.

Comment: Do you have more than one mounted file system? Are you using ZFS or jails?

Comment: No jails. Does that matter? The question is not related to any particular filesystem, but to the recommended HIER place.

Comment: What do you consider  "data" and "contents"? Is there a difference?

Comment: Contents may be media. Data means dynamically generated user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few more years of experience, I think I can self-answer:

- If uploaded into `/var/www`, it must be stored somewhere but outside of the DocumentRoot. With this approach, the backup is easier, as the backup scripts can simply take the entire `/var/www` folder and subfolders, with data and code.
- Another suitable place is `/var/` . As stated in [Chapter 3. FreeBSD Basics - 3.5. Directory Structure](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/dirstructure.html#:%7E:text=The%20FreeBSD%20directory%20hierarchy%20is,system%20for%20multi%2Duser%20operation).

> `/var/`   Multi-purpose log, temporary, transient, and spool files. A memory-based file > system is sometimes mounted at `/var`. This can be automated using the `varmfs-relate`

- Ultimately, user Apache may have a `/home` folder created to read/write data.